# Property 'snapshot' doesnot exist on type 'typeof ActivatedRoute'

Tags: angular

I am using ActivatedRoute for passing id to another route. But when i use snapshot like:

```
let studentCode = this._activatedroute.snapshot.params['id']
```

it gives an error: `Property 'snapshot' does not exist on type 'typeof ActivatedRoute'.`
here `id` is the id to be passed that I used in ngFor iteration.

Full component code where activated route is used:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import{ StudentHttpServService } from '../show-students/student-http-serv.service';
import {Router, ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
import {Inject} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-classes-component',
  templateUrl: './classes-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./classes-component.component.css']
})
export class studentDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(@Inject(StudentHttpServService) private __astudentHttpServService: StudentHttpServService, @Inject(ActivatedRoute) private _activatedroute = ActivatedRoute, @Inject(Router) private _router:Router) { 

   }


  ngOnInit() {

//this._StudentHttpServService.getstudentDetailsHttpSrv()
let studentCode = this._activatedroute.snapshot.params['id']

  }

}
```

Pls let me know if i need to give code for router in app.module.ts or the iteration code (html and ts files). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use **`:`** instead of **`=`**

```
 @Inject(ActivatedRoute) private _activatedroute : ActivatedRoute
```

**Corrected Code:**

```
 constructor(@Inject(StudentHttpServService) private __astudentHttpServService: StudentHttpServService, @Inject(ActivatedRoute) private _activatedroute : ActivatedRoute, @Inject(Router) private _router:Router) { 

   }
```